# Why is add_rewrite_endpoint incompatible with /%category%/%postname%/ permalink structure?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I've added a `myvar/myvalue` rewrite endpoint to `EP_ALL` which can be added to any URL of a WP installation and a WP plugin will act upon it. That part is cool but it doesn't work when the permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/`. It works well with all the built in, selectable structures. There could be other structures it doesn't work with.

**Doesn't work = 404 error.**

The path looks something like this: `/mycategory/mypost/myvar/myvalue`

I got the Rewrite analyzer plugin which tells me that it's interpreted as (top 4, in order):

---

This is not it... (highlighted with yellow)

`(.?.+?)/myvar(/(.*))?/?$`
pagename: mycategory/mypost
myvar: myvalue

---

Apparently this gets used but it's still cold...

`.?.+?/([^/]+)/myvar(/(.*))?/?$`
attachment: mypost
myvar: /myvalue

---

Plain wrong...

`(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$`
pagename: mycategory/mypost/myvar
page: /myvalue

---

**This is it, but it fails to realize it!**

`(.+?)/([^/]+)/myvar(/(.*))?/?$`
category_name: mycategory
name: mypost
myvar: myvalue

---

And I'm outputting `global $query_string;` which tells me it's
`attachment=mypost&myvar=%2Fmyvalue` (by the way it shouldn't include the %2f - slash).

So can someone enlighten me if this is a bug in WP, or is there something I can do about it?

My idea is roughly this
 `if ( '/%category%/%postname%/' == $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure ){ ... }`
and manually telling WP the category and the name and displaying that content. But I don't know what goes as `...` and what should I hook this into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't it work? I'm not sure. That particular pattern is the same as a parent/child page request, WordPress has to do some extra queries to determine if a post exists by that name, or if it's a page. Why this breaks when you add an endpoint, I haven't delved into the code to determine.

How can you make it work? It appears that if you don't use the `EP_ALL` mask and instead use the OR operator with all the individual masks, it will build the rules in such a way where those endpoints will correctly resolve.

For example:

```
function wpa_myvar_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'myvar', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_myvar_endpoint' );
```

Comment: HA! It works, thank you. The rewrite analyzer puts the previously 3rd and 4th row into the 2nd and 3rd position by having that 2nd row with the `attachment` + `myvar` interpretation completely gone! Is your `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES` equivalent to `EP_ALL` in practice? I really need the `myvar/mayvalue` combination to be able to be added to any URL.

Comment: `add_rewrite_endpoint($this->settings['myvar'], EP_PERMALINK | EP_DATE | EP_YEAR | EP_MONTH | EP_DAY | EP_ROOT | EP_COMMENTS | EP_SEARCH | EP_CATEGORIES | EP_TAGS | EP_AUTHORS | EP_PAGES);` looks quite interesting, I'm omitting just the EP_ATTACHMENT.